# Dynamic Android app languages

Tags: android

Many times I've seen Android apps that have a list of languages displayed and I can tap on any of this language and download it for this specific app (GO Weather widget has this functionality).

I'm interested in how is this implemented and what is the best way to load languages dynamically in Android apps? Adding 100 string.xml resources in app project is not a solution and besides if I want to provide some kind of "funny holiday language" pack or add a new language I would need to upload the project to Google Play again and again...

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any solution in mind or is this just a vague thought ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it's possible to use [Expansion Files](http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html) to add on to your app, they are limited in some ways. The main problem for you would be that you can only have a limited number of expansion files. If you wanted 100 languages, your only option would be to load them *all* in the expansion file, and download the whole thing. While that might not be a problem, since a list of translated strings probably isn't that large, you may want to go a different route.

The best option I see for downloading *separate* language add-ons is to forgo using `strings.xml` altogether. Just use a simple CSV file to hold your strings, mapping names to strings. When your program starts, read it in to a string array/map/whatever, and you have all your strings at the ready. This way, if you want to add a language, it's as easy as downloading a text file and saving it to your data directory.

Also, you can keep a file listing all the available languages on the same server, so you don't have to update the app if you want to add seasonal or limited-time-only languages, like you mentioned. Just read in the file to get the list.

Note, you'll need somewhere to host the files, but that's hardly a barrier in this day and age.

Comment: I think this way it would be the best solution. Thanks for you answer! I will go in this direction ;)

Comment: hay there! any improvements anyone implemented using the above method or is there any other method.